# Issues using localStorage to pass form data between HTML Pages

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage, frontend

I have been trying to input values in the form and click the submit button to go to the new tip.html page, then use the console to view localstorage but I get this error  when I type localStorage in the console of the tip.html page:

> VM223:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage'
> property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document. at
> :1:1

How can I send my form data from the home.html page to the tip.html page?

What is wrong here?
Or is there an easier way of doing what I want to get done?

Files:

The bottom of this page has my form :
https://github.com/ScarletMcLearn/UniThings/blob/master/CSC%20-%20Web/Assignment%201/src/home.html

(This form: https://hastebin.com/ogikekaxal.xml)

This page has the webpage that the form submit action takes to :
https://github.com/ScarletMcLearn/UniThings/blob/master/CSC%20-%20Web/Assignment%201/src/tip.html

(This HTML page : https://hastebin.com/dotejuperi.xml)

And this final file is my Jquery File which has the function dealing with the submit button :

https://github.com/ScarletMcLearn/UniThings/blob/master/CSC%20-%20Web/Assignment%201/src/script.js

(Submit Button Function : https://hastebin.com/sisugehede.http)

Here is the entire repository : https://github.com/ScarletMcLearn/UniThings/tree/master/CSC%20-%20Web/Assignment%201

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you are trying to load your script from a different domain than the html page is loaded from, I think. You should load them both from the same domain. This setting is intentionally set to off in chrome and I would not recommend disabling it.

**Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.**

> This exception is thrown when the "Block third-party cookies and site data" checkbox is set in Content Settings.
>
> To find the setting, open Chrome settings, type "third" in the search box, click the Content Settings button, and view the fourth item under Cookies.
>
> If this setting is checked, third-party scripts cookies are disallowed and access to localStorage may result in thrown SecurityError exceptions.

[Source](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document)

Comment: Might be worth adding a note about why this security setting is in place and why you should really be careful when disabling this setting in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

- You could use javascript to load the html dynamically (for example with jQary without changing the url by clicking) and save your data in a global variable.
- Or you can pass the data in the url (after ?) as param or hash and than read from the other page